# Multiple one to many relationships from a single table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Don't know if it was ever considered correct, but back in the day, I'd use UniqueIdentifiers for all of my Id's, and I could attach tables in really convoluted and awesome ways.

Now I'm using MVC and Entity, and I have a problem.  I may be missing something very simple.

I have a File Upload model, and I have many online Forms, each of which is a model (or viewmodel).  I'd like to have the File Upload model entirely generalized, and be able to be host a one to many relationship with any number of the Form models.  Any of the Forms should be able to be associated with a set of File Uploads at design time, and then the user can do the uploads.

How do I do this?

Comment: use `interface` and create a method or properties (or both) to be shared between all related models. Then, use this interface on your calls.

Comment: You can use an `abstract` base `Form model` to have a `one to many` relation with `FileUpload model` and `Form model` will have a `one to one` relation with various types of Forms.